# Action as a optional parameter in a function

Tags: c#, action, optional-parameters

Is it possible to have an Action as an optional parameter in a function? The button2Action should be optional.

```
public void DrawWindow(Rect p_PositionAndSize, string p_Button2Text = "NotInUse", Action p_Button2Action)
{
 // Stuff happens here
}
```

I tried it with e.g `p_Button2Action = delegate{ Debug.Log("NotInUse"); }` but it does not compile due to **Default parameter value for p_Button2Action must be a compile-time constant.** How do you make an optional Action that is a compile time constant?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must specify a constant value for a default parameter, so the only default value you can specify for an Action is null.

However, it's easy to check for null and substitute the correct value:

```
public void DrawWindow(Rect p_PositionAndSize, string p_Button2Text = "NotInUse", Action p_Button2Action = null)
{
    if (p_Button2Action == null)
        p_Button2Action = delegate{ Debug.Log("NotInUse"); }

    ...
}
```

Comment: if you want null as default action you can use:  p_Button2Action?.Invoke();

Comment: @RMazitov Note that the null coalescing operator is only available in C# 6 or later - so it's correct to use that now (but obviously it didn't exist in 2013)

Comment: yes, good point. thanks for bringing that up)

Answer (score 4):

One workaround for this may be to just use classical overloading:

```
public void DrawWindow(Rect p_PositionAndSize, string p_Button2Text = "NotInUse")
{
    DrawWindow(p_PositionAndSize, delegate{ Thread.Sleep(1); }, p_Button2Text);
}

public void DrawWindow(Rect p_PositionAndSize, Action p_Button2Action, string p_Button2Text = "NotInUse")
{
 // Stuff happens here
}
```

This way you can specify the default action in the overload with two parameters.